Calling Python script from command line gives, "NameError: name 'convert_json_to_csv' is not defined"
I have a Python script, convert_json_to_csv.py.
When I hit return I get error, "NameError: name 'convert_json_to_csv' is not defined".

Below is the script's contents:
import pandas as pd

json_file_path = 'trulab.json' # Path to your JSON file
csv_file_path = 'trulab.csv' # Path where CSV file will be saved

def json_to_csv(json_file_path, csv_file_path):
    # Read JSON file into a dataframe
    df = pd.read_json(json_file_path, lines=True)
    
    # Save dataframe to a CSV file, delimited by a pipe
    df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False, sep='|')

json_to_csv(json_file_path, csv_file_path)

I tried to run script from command line.
I was expecting Python to run the script
but it seems it 'thinks' my script is an undefined variable.
I am brand new to Python.

Your command to start python is wrong, you have invoked the Python intercative shell. You should provide the name of your script to start it thus: python convert_json_to_csv.py.

Thank you.  Okay gotcha, I just thought the python script would work in the python interactive shell.  But running from a pure windows command works, now I just have to add the 'panda' module !
Thank you for your time and help!
"
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\dclad>python convert_json_to_csv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dclad\convert_json_to_csv.py", line 1, in 
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
C:\Users\dclad>
"

How do I mark "OldBoy's" comment as the answer ?

I have done it, so you can mark that if you wish.

Does this answer your question? python3 --version shows "NameError: name 'python3' is not defined"

Your command to start python is wrong, you have invoked the Python interactive shell. You should provide the name of your script to start it thus:
python convert_json_to_csv.py

If the import statement says "module not found" it means that you have not installed pandas on your system. Try the following command:
pip install pandas

